# Printing elements of "hash of hash of array" in perl

Tags: perl, hash

I need to print the elements of the following "hash of hash of array"(%partitions).
 But nothing is getting printed. Also, No error is encountered. Please help

```
our %partitions;
sub partition{
    my %set;
    my @array;
    for(my $i=0;$i<$pop_size;$i++)
    {   
        for(my $j=0;$j<$min_PR;$j++)
        {
            @array=();
            for(my $k=0;$k<$tot_nodes;$k++)
            {
                if($population[$i]{$k} eq $j)
                {
                    push @array, $k;
                }
            }
            $set{$j} = [@array];
        }    
        $partitions{$i} = [%set];
    }    
    foreach $p (sort keys %partitions)
    {
        print "$p {\n";
        while (my ($r, $s) = %{$partitions->{$p}}) # Error in this line
        {                                          # Not entering this loop
            print "$r {\n";
            print "value: @$s \n";
            print "}\n";
        }
    }       
}

partition;
```

Comment: Hello @user3503560, can you please provide a sample input (which is a hash of hash of array as you mentioned) and output so we can help you debug this better?

Comment: You could use `Data::Dumper` to print your data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you could benefit from [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html), because there are several oddities in your code that could use fixing.

```
$partitions{$i} = [%set];
```

This creates an array reference containing a flattened version of the hash `%set`, which probably isn't what you intend.  I think you may have meant this:

```
$partitions{$i} = { %set };
```

but I also think maybe `%set` should be declared inside that outer loop.

(On further reading, maybe you *did* mean to flatten it.)

This line:

```
while (my ($r, $s) = %{$partitions->{$p}}) # Error in this line
```

should probably be:

```
while (my ($r, $s) = each %{$partitions{$p}})
```

Comment: I actually meant to create a reference to a hash(using {}). But unknowingly i created a reference to array (using []). Thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

I think this could work..:

Change this:

```
 while (my ($r, $s) = %{$partitions->{$p}})
```

For this:

```
my $ref = \%partitions;
while (my ($r, $s) = %{$ref->{$p}})
```

Or this:

```
while (my ($r, $s) = %{${\%partitions}->{$p}})
```